# Android Adapter for spinner (passing context in fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-spinner, android-context

I can't find the way to pass the context to adapter for spinner in static fragment (onCreateView() function):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
.
.
.

    public static class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    .
    .
    .

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       .
       .
       .
        spinner1.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(MainActivity.this, spinner1, spinnerValues));
        spinner2.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, spinner1, spinnerValues));
        spinner3.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, spinner1, spinnerValues));
   .
   .
   .
```

I even tried to create static class that conteined static method returning context, but didn't work neither.

That's MyAdapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
        super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt);
    }
    public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
        return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
    }
    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);
        TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner
                .findViewById(R.id.text_main_seen);
        main_text.setText(spinnerValues[position]);
        return mySpinner;
    }
}
```

Edit: I'm receiving an error: "MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  It looks like your adapter takes a context in its constructor and is receiving an Activity context just fine.

Comment: Well, I'm receiving an error: "MainActivity.this cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: Please edit the question and include that detail along with the full class where it's being used.

Comment: you don't need to make any class static. It has it's own problems which you will understand as you become more experienced. Is the fragment part of MainActivity? if not then, instead of "this" and "mainActivity.this", use getActivity(). Check if this helps.

Comment: Edited it.
@suku - it doesn't help ;(

Comment: can you provide the error after unmaking the class static

Comment: Then it says i cannot apply a spinner to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `getActivity()` or `yourParentView.getContext()`.

- this - [return self reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)
- getContext() - [return Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)
- getActivity() - [return Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)

**Context**
As the name suggests, its the context of current state of the application/object. It lets newly created objects understand what has been going on. Typically you call it to get information regarding another part of your program (activity, package/application)

**Activity**
Activity is a Java code that supports a screen or UI. In other words, building block of the user interface is the activity. Activity class is a pre-defined class in Android and every application which has UI must inherit it to create window. Activity represents the presentation layer of an Android application, e.g. a screen which the user sees. An Android application can have several activities and it can be switched between them during runtime of the application.

**Note : Activity extends Context. Context not a Activity.**

Comment: @BasitAnwer I have update my answer, **Vote up** if you satisfied with answer.

Comment: Done. Please always try to explain the answer so that other users may benefit from the question and your answer.

Comment: @BasitAnwer Thank you for your suggestion, I will do it from now :)